# DRBD as a block device for XEN VM (Centos 5.3)

Tags: xen, drbd

I have setup a drbd resource between 2 server nodes - everything works correctly when doing sync tests between the two. (I want to create a HA cluster using drbd,xen and heartbeat)

However, when I try and create a XEN VM with Centos as guest operating system, I get through to the partitioning screen on the install but when I select a partitioning type the next screen gives me the following error :

"An error has occurred - no valid devices 
were found on which to create new file
systems. Please check your hardware for
the cause of this problem."

This is the first time attempting create a setup like this and searching Google does not help much...

my config files for DRBD and XEN....

DRBD (just the section that is pertinent)

on xennode0 {
  device     /dev/drbd0;
  disk       /dev/sda5;
  address    X.X.X.X:7788;
  flexible-meta-disk  internal;
}

on xennode1 {
  device    /dev/drbd0;
  disk      /dev/sda5;
  address   X.X.X.X:7788;
  meta-disk internal;
}

XEN

kernel = "/boot/xeninstall/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/boot/xeninstall/initrd.img"
extra = "text"
name = "VM"
maxmem = 3000
memory = 3000
vcpus = 4
on_poweroff = "destroy"
on_reboot = "restart"
on_crash = "restart"
vfb = [  ]
disk = [ "phy:/dev/drbd0,sda1,w", "tap:aio:/srv/xen/xenswap.img,sda2,w" ]
vif = [ "mac=00:16:3e:11:67:ae,bridge=xenbr0" ]
root = "/dev/sda1 ro"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the output of mount please? Is this problem to do with installing CentOS or formatting and installing a new DRBD partition?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the reply... 

The problem is with installing a domU. The dom0 is working correctly... 

the output of mount... 

/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw) 
devpts on /dev/pts type 
devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620) 
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw) 
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw) 
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw) 
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw) 
none on /var/lib/xenstored type tmpfs (rw)

Answer (score 5):

Well, seeing as though I pulled my hair out solving this, let me answer my question and save someone else the trouble of hair pulling :)

Solution:

After playing around, plenty of Googling and repartitioning etc... I came to a setup that works like a charm.

There is probably a quicker way to do this but I am not going to over complicate this answer

I did a standard install with the partitions like this (I have a 500g hard drive) :

```
/boot 100mb 
/swap 4gb 
/     40gb
```

The balance of the disk space is to be left as unpartitioned space.

Then, I created a primary partition called /dev/sda4 by following these steps:

```
~: fdisk /dev/sda
~: (fdisk shell) p4   (for primary partition # 4)
~: (fdisk shell) t    (hit t and enter to edit the partition type)
~: (fdisk shell) 08e  (Linux LVM)
```

Reboot the server so that the new partitions can take effect.

Now create logical volumes by:

```
~: pvcreate /dev/sda4
~: vgcreate xenvg -s 4M /dev/sda4    # (xenvg is the name of my virtual group, you can rename it)
~: lvcreate -L400G -n xenroot xenvg  # (xenroot is going to be my drbd  resource and root partition for my DomU)
~: lvcreate -L4G  -n xenswap xenvg   # (xenswap is my swap file for my DomU)
```

Now that you have the correct partitioning you can go ahead and install DRBD with the following config file directives (drbd.conf)

Just displaying the 2 important directives here...

```
{
device  /dev/drbd0;
disk    /dev/xenvg/xenroot;
}
```

Your XEN VM config file needs to look like this (again, just the important one)

```
{
disk = [ "drbd:xenvm,xvda,w","phy:xenvg/xenswap,xvdb,w" ]
}
```

I hope this helps someone out there...

Answer (score 0):

So there are two points that are important here:

1. It's better to use whole disks instead of partitions for the device the DomU will see
2. Use standard-device-names within the DomU (xvd*)

I stumbled across the latter with the newest SLES SP3 Kernel Patch:
Up to then I was using "sda" as device-name within the DomU.

Now my paravirtualized DomUs just hung during the application of the kernel-patch.
An strace of the patch-process showed me that something was trying to access sda as if it were a physical disk. After changing sda to xvda I had no problems any more.

With CentOS 4 as paravirtualized DomU it was quite tricky to use "sda", too. I had to convince the system not to use the scsi-driver for that device, but the xenblock-driver instead. Basically the same problem.